# Why does glimpse() drop some digits for large numbers and how to prevent rounding

Tags: r

I like `glimpse()` from `tidyverse` to show a single numeric vector of large numbers without rounding, just as it does when inspecting the entire dataframe.

Good.

```
glimpse(mtcars)
Rows: 32
Columns: 11
$ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9…
$ cyl  <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4
$ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472.0, 460.0, 440.0,…
$ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, …
$ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3.00, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22…
$ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440, 4.070, 3.730, 3.780, 5.250, 5.424, 5.345,…
$ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90, 17.40, 17.60, 18.00, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42,…
$ vs   <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ am   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
$ gear <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
$ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2
```

Good.

```
glimpse(mtcars$mpg)
num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
```

Not good. I don't need the rounding.

```
glimpse(mtcars$disp)
num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
```

Comment: It's not rounding anything, just not showing xx.0 isn't called rounding!

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do something with `?pillar::pillar_options`.  (I would have thought that `options(pillar.sigfig = 4)` would work, but it doesn't.)

If you `[`-index rather than using `$`, you'll get a one-column tibble that will be formatted according to tibble rules:

```r
glimpse(mtcars["disp"])
```

```
Rows: 32
Columns: 1
$ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 16…
```

Alternatively: it looks like `glimpse()` falls back to the base-R function `str()` when printing atomic vectors.  From `?str`, this seems to do what you want (change both the default number of digits and the trailing-zero behaviour):

```r
options(str = strOptions(digits.d = 4, formatNum = function(x, ...)
                            format(x, trim = TRUE, drop0trailing = FALSE, ...)))
glimpse(mtcars$disp)
 num [1:32] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 ...
```